# Rate of growth of a function and its derivative

Tags: limits, derivatives

This is a really stupid problem I'm stuck on. Please help!

Let $\phi(x)=x(x-1)^2$, then  $\phi'(x)=(x-1)^2+2x(x-1)$ and $-\phi'(x)=-(x-1)^2-2x(x-1)$.

Clearly $\frac{-\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)}=\frac{-1}{x}-\frac{2}{x-1}$, so $$\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{-\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)}=-1+\infty=\infty$$.

**question 1:** both $\phi'(x)$ and $-\phi(x)$ are going to zero as $x\to1^-$. but still $$\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{-\phi'(x)}{\phi(x)}=\infty$$.
Hence $\phi(x)$ goes to zero at a faster rate than $-\phi'(x)$ at $x=1^-$. is this correct?

**question 2**
looking at their graphs we can see that $-\phi'(x)$ has a more vertical slope, near $x=1^-$. and a graph with a more vertical slope increases or decreases at a faster rate. Hence, $-\phi'(x)$ goes to zero faster than $\phi(x)$ at $x=1^-$. is this correct?

[image]

**question 3:**
as far as I can see, there are only 3 ways options here, when comparing the rate at which $\phi(x)$ and $-\phi'(x)$ are going to zero at $x=1^-$

1. $\phi$ is going to zero at a faster rate
2. $-\phi'$ is going to zero at a faster rate
3. both are going to zero at the same rate

which one is the correct option?

Comment: Consider how $\lim_{x \to 0^+}\frac{x}{x^2}=\infty$, even though $x^2$ has a much shallower gradient around $0$ compared to $x$. The point is that for small $x$, we see that $x^2$ becomes orders of magnitude smaller than $x$.

Comment: so, even though x is going to zero at a faster rate, $x^2$ is so much closer to zero, that $x^2$ reaches there first, despite being slower. is that correct? @Joe

Answer (score 1):

This could be taken as an exercise in Taylor series. Expand $\phi$ and $\phi'$ in their Taylor polynomial:

$$ \frac{\phi'}{\phi} = \frac{\phi'(1) + \phi''(1) (x-1) ...}{\phi(1) + \phi'(1) +\phi''(1) \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}...}$$

Note that: $\phi(1) = \phi'(1)=0$, hence:

$$ \frac{\phi'}{\phi} = \frac{2+ \left(... \right)}{ (x-1) +\left[O (x-1)^2 ....\right]}$$

Now notice that this new function has a singularity at $x=1$, really the derivatives don't control the limit since their dependence cancel out. For more details , see my article on Taylor [here](https://buraian.medium.com/a-brief-introduction-to-taylor-series-47416e7b9123). It was written by a high schooler for high schoolers.

Comment: this doesn't really answer my question. what i am asking is why does the slope look more vertical for $-\phi'$, when $\phi$ is going to 0 at a faster rate?

Comment: I am saying the rate at going to zero is independent of the second derivative( and also the zeroth and first derivative because  they are zero), so it makes no sense to talk of rates, at least here @abhishek

Comment: please note, I am referring to the derivatives of $\phi$. I meant it makes no sense to talk about rates, because there is an unavoidable singularity at $x=1$

Comment: i am not talking about the rates at x=1, but the rates just before x=1, i.e at $x=1^-$

Comment: If you recall l'hopitals rule, the limit depends on ratio of rates at the limit point , and  no other point

Comment: limits never depends on what happens at the limit point.

Comment: see-->https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function

Comment: press ctrl+f and type--->limit does not depend on f

Comment: Asssuming $f'(a)  \neq 0 $ and $g'(a) \neq 0 $ then $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f}{g} = \frac{f'}{g'}$ if $f(0)=g(0)$, my point was that if everything is well define it is directly dependent on ratio at limits points.

Comment: for l'hopitals rule you do not need to assume that $f'(a)\neq0$ and if $\infty$ is an accepted value for the limit, you do not need to assume $g'(a)\neq 0$

Comment: Ok yeah, I went a bit too fast there, basically I want it to be a condition such that I can directly plug it in and the exp would be evaluated without too many problems